# How to change configure cassandra properties listed in the CassandraRelevantProperties class?

Tags: cassandra

`CassandraRelevantProperties` have default values for many of its system properties. However, I am not able to link them with settings in the `cassandra.yaml` file. In particular, I want to set the `SAI_VECTOR_ALLOW_CUSTOM_PARAMETERS` to true to configure the vector index. Can I do that with any configuration file without rebuilding cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

With `CassandraRelevantProperties` what has changed is how system properties are accessed within the codebase, but they are still passed as system properties when executing the process, see https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/docs/managing/configure/cassandra-system-properties.html. If you're changing the contents of `cassandra.yaml`, make sure to pass the correct location via -Dcassandra.config and restart the node.

I wasn't able to find a reference to SAI_VECTOR_ALLOW_CUSTOM_PARAMETERS in Cassandra's system properties or `cassandra.yaml`, so I'm not sure where this configuration would go or look like.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is that I cannot link the properties in the `CasandraRelevantProperties` source file with those documented in the `cassandra.yaml`. Do you have an example of a property set in `cassandra.yaml` has a corresponding field in `CasandraRelevantProperties`? Btw SAI_VECTOR_ALLOW_CUSTOM_PARAMETERS is at this line <https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/ed5a22428355765df5da94151413fc59538afef5/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/config/CassandraRelevantProperties.java#L460>.

Comment: I don't think these settings can be configured via the cassandra.yaml file. There are several ways [https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/docs/managing/configure/start-up-parameters.html](to set system properties during startup), try executing `cassandra -Dcassandra.sai.vector.allow_custom_parameters=true` and see if that works. Depending how to manage processes in your server you may need to see what way of passing system properties is adequate.